# multile websites using lighttpd? I.E. just 2 for now

Tags: pi-4, web-server, internet, lighttpd, nginx

i am using bullseye on a pi 4.
would like to understand the configutaion files on how do i set up 2 websites to be accessed from the Internet?

Comment: You configure the software the same way on any Linux box.  Look for a Linux solution.

Comment: tried this .............. https://tecadmin.net/setup-virtualhosts-in-lighttpd-server/ ......... to no luck

Comment: lighttpd    - Check config file
/bin/bash: line 1: /etc/lighttpd/djb.ownip.net.conf: Permission denied
2022-06-19 14:25:26: configfile.c.2113) command "/etc/lighttpd/djb.ownip.net.conf" exited non-zero: 126
2022-06-19 14:25:26: configfile.c.1970) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 51 pos: 14 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL)